# Canonical projection on Quotient space maps open ball to open ball

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

I’m struggling to understand the last part of this proof where it says $\pi(x)=\pi(x-z)$ proves the claim. To prove the claim I suppose this must imply that $||x|| \leqslant ||x-z||$ so that $||x||<1$ also and thus $x$ belongs to the open unit ball in $E$.

I can’t see how this implies this.

In case this is not standard, I have in my notes $\pi : E \rightarrow E/E_0$ , $x \mapsto x+E_0$ is the canonical projection where $E_0$ is a closed subspace of the normed space $E$ and the quotient norm is defined to be $||x +E_0||:= inf\{||x-z||:z\in E_0\}$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to find some $y\in E$ with $\|y\|\lt 1$ such that $\pi(y)=x+E_0$.( In other words, the preimage of $x+E_0$ intersects the open unit ball in $E$ non-trivially.) The element $x-z$ is such a choice.

Comment: One more thing. In the proof is not just showing it holds for the open unit ball centred at zero? Because it only checks for $||x-0||=||x||<1$? I don’t see how this generalises to being in the open ball of an arbitrary point in the normed space.

Comment: Well, $B(0,1)+\{z\}=B(z,1)$ for all $z\in E$.

Comment: Is it simply $||x||<1 \implies||\pi(x)||<1$ and therefore $||x-a||<1 \implies ||\pi(x-a)||=||\pi(x)-\pi(a)||<1$?

Comment: You have to show the converse as well. Informally, you have $$\pi(B(z,1))=\pi(B(0,1)+z)=\pi(B(0,1))+\pi(z)=B_{E/E_0}(0,1)+(z+E_0)=B_{E/E_0}(z+E_0,1).$$